# Rename a MySQL table using SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to rename an existing table using SQL statement:

I have already tried:

1. `mysql_query("RENAME '$renameFolder' TO '$newName'");`
2. `mysql_query("ALTER TABLE '$renameFolder' RENAME TO '$newName'");`
3. `mysql_query("RENAME TABLE '$renameFolder' TO '$newName'");`

Using any of the 3 statements I'm always getting the same error message:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax"

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: Try: "RENAME TABLE $renameFolder TO $newName"

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using backquotes instead, e.g.:

```
mysql_query( "RENAME TABLE `" . $renameFolder . "` TO `" . $newname . "`" );
```

Comment: I think it is that. logically we have to warp table name betwin ` not '.

Comment: I tried it on my own set up and removing the quotes fixed it. I suspect that you have non-alphanumeric characters in your table name. Try it with ` quotes instead as atragis said.

Comment: do you mean like that:  mysql_query("RENAME " . '$renameFolder' . " TO ". '$newName')   ?

Answer (score 2):

The mysql query for rename table is 
`RENAME TABLE old_name TO new_name`

Answer (score 2):

**appected** answer from mySQLi:

```
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","database");
$oldFolder="old_table_name";
$newname="new_table_name";
mysqli_query($db,"RENAME TABLE `" . $oldFolder . "` TO `" . $newname . "`");
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Have you connected to the server properly?

Have you selected the db the table is in?

If you have, then you should be able to run this:

```
mysql_query("ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO new_table_name");
```

Comment: Yes the table is in. i aready used this statement and is not working for me.

Comment: Then you have to put `` around the table names or concatenate the strings with the variables as suggested by Overv.

Answer (score 1):

```
RENAME TABLE `jshop`.`mob_apple` TO `jshop`.`item_mobile`;
```

Answer (score 1):

With `mysqli object oriented interface` you can use the following to rename your table

```
 $sql = "RENAME TABLE OldName TO NewName";
//if the query is successful
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Table  renamed successfully";
}
//If something goes wrong

 else {
 echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it without the quotes so the final query will look like:

```
mysql_query ("ALTER TABLE foo RENAME TO bar");
```

Hope this helps.