# HttpPost java to Server/Mysql renaming

Tags: java, php, mysql, http-post

I use an HttpPost Object in Java to communicate with my server that manage a Mysql database. So there is a receiver php page that manage every type of requests. 
If I insert/delete/update data there is no problem. But now I need to rename a table and I find out that other types of operations are not correctly executed too (for example: truncate table..).

Finally I found this post [Rename a MySQL table using SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549243/rename-a-mysql-table-using-sql-statement) but it doesn't work in my project..

What about this particular situation? Any suggestion? Maybe something about permissions?

Thank you!

Comment: How do you mean, not correctly executed? What is happening? GENERALLY speaking, you do not use http requests for renaming/truncating/etc tables. POST is for creating, PUT is for updating, GET is for selecting, DELETE is for deleting, etc. They are meant for those types of operations.

Comment: The table is not renamed as I requested: "RENAME TABLE TCS TO ATS;".
I need to do this automatically because there is a process, executed every day, to manage data. My problem occurs during the update: if the process is updating the database, users can download inconsistent data..